# I cannot display ebook content on the Kobo ebook app

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo, apps

I have purchased an ebook from Rakuten Kobo, downloaded ebook app on my computer, I see my book on the ebook, but cannot seem to display the book. I have tried clicking on the book, I clicked on different icons, but to no avail. How do get to see the see the ebook, so I can read it?

Comment: Welcome to SE-ebooks. This is an abnormal situation apparently.
Please make sure you give all information available. For example,
knowing what type of computer you are using might help.
Also, do not forget to give feed back to users who answer.
This can be useful to other users who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) as an ebook reading app. It works well in many different environments and accepts many ebook formats. I buy lots of books in epub, from Kobo and others, and I never had any problem reading them with Calibre (though I prefer my small Kobo ebook reader).

Trying it would at least check whether there is a problem with the ebook.

Another point is that you did not tell whether your ebook has [DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) (usually Adobe DRM in the case of Kobo). I am not sure whether that would require special steps to get the book displayed, but I suspect it would, at least for the first book.  I cannot say more on that because I simply refuse to buy books with DRM, and have thus no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Kobo app, if you go to the `MY BOOKS` tab, you can double-click the book you want to read or right-click and select `Read now`. The book will open in the window and title will be displayed as a tab at the top.